# Unable to add Roboto font to Rails 6 using TailwindCSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, google-fonts

Currently I'm trying to use Roboto in my application to have a font similar to [five thirty eight](https://fivethirtyeight.com/). However, when I try to edit the configuration for Tailwind and restart the server I don't see the font.

Here is the the link I'm using to load the font that I got from  [google fonts:](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)

```
  <head>
    <title>ArtsyDecor</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all',  'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
```

I then added the Roboto font to the `tailwind.config.js` on my rails app.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: '"Roboto"'
      display: ['"Roboto"', '"sans-serif"'],
      body: ['"Roboto"', '"sans-serif"'],
    },
    extend: {}
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
}
```

But when I restart the server I don't see Roboto being the main font. It seems the tailwind configuration is being overwritten somewhere.
[image]

What seems to be wrong?

Comment: It worked with me when I moved the font import in `tailwind.css` file (which contains the base, component and utilities imports)

Answer (score 2):

try installing Roboto into your project with NPM instead of the CDN:
`yarn add typeface-roboto`

Answer (score 0):

It work when you add `@import url(....)` in your main Tailwind file `app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css`

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a typo. the font is defined in single and double quotes. use only single or double quotes.